# Using GParted(attached screenshot), how do I move the unallocated to the right side of my main ubuntu partition so I can extend it

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, gparted

Goal:

I wanted to shrink more my windows partition into at least 100 GB more and add that to the current unallocated 107.42 GB space. My main goal is to extend /dev/sda8(main ubuntu partition) to use the unallocated space. I watched this video [Extend Ubuntu Disk Volume with GParted after Resizing Hard Drive](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cDgUwWkvuIY), but I cant move/resize /dev/sda8 to the left side of unalloc or move unalloc to the right side of /dev/sda8. How can I get pass through the left of ext4, grub2core, and linux-swap.

Info and question from my screenshot:

1. /dev/sda4 is my windows partition
2. /dev/sda8 is my main ubuntu partition
3. Where is my extended here?

[GParted screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HjAwc.png)

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, your Ubuntu OS is on sda5. It's impossible moving all Linux partitions by GParted as you expect. 1) Grub bootloader issue 2) backup and restore all the Linux partitions after Windows ones.

Comment: So how do I resolve this?

Comment: If your Ubuntu OS doesn't have anything important. You can simply erase it and re-install it again. If you want to keep all the data, you should use clonezilla or `fsarchiver` to backup and restore.

Comment: Man I have to install all over again the dependencies and setting up for dev environment

Comment: Can you lead me to a link where I can learn using clonezilla or fsarchiver. I had deleted my ubuntu bootable on my usb

Comment: Your screenshot indicates that a partition you want to edit is mounted (you are booted into Ubuntu from it!) You cannot do that. You must boot from a LiveUSB to make those changes. Looks like you did a classic new-user mistake and over-partitioned instead of using the installer defaults. Remember that partitioning and re-partitioning is *risky*, so have backups before you begin. Advice: Always take good notes on how to rebuild your installed environment to avoid a lot of problems.

Comment: Also you can't move unallocated space, instead move the partitons `sda5`, `sda6`,and `sda7` to the left, then the unallocated space will be adjecant to `sda8`.

Comment: I have had very good luck using the free version of AOMEI Partition Assistant Standard Edition 8.5 to move and shrink Windows partitions as you describe. I have not had good luck using Linux apps including GParted.

Comment: To backup your disk, you need an external storage and bootable CD/DVD/USB. [clonezilla](https://clonezilla.org/) and [fsarchiver and system rescue](http://www.system-rescue-cd.org/) latter one is handy for multiple occasion and require linux knowledge than clonezilla.

Answer (score 0):

**Resort to this method if no other is available**

Not that kind of similar situation, but check if this works out..i'm not that sure but anyway:

1) Go to windows, install AOMEI partition assistant(idk about 
   versions). Run it.

2) In that, select the unallocated space, right click-merge.
   A dialog box appears to which partition you must merge this 
   unallocated space. Select the last partition, i.e the one 
   which you want to expand.

(**Now here's the thing... I've done this to extend my last windows ntfs partition with unallocated spaces made from multiple windows partitions lying before it. In your case, if AOMEI detects your linux partitions, then you might be able to excecute this operation successfully. If everything goes well, then another dialog box appears asking how to do the operation. Here, the first option,(default) through win PE environment has to be selected. Then proceed. Upon next win startup, the operation commences**.)

***please don't held me accountable for, if anything goes wrong. This is a tight operation, especially since it is not a windows partition and risks are there. Backup any imp data***

plz, if anybody else knows about the software, correct me if i'm wrong...........